# Proteus 8 - broken simulation

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, 8051

Hi I'm new to using proteus to simulate my microcontroller code and circuit. Every time I run the simulation all the LEDs disappear and the wires go white.
I'm not sure why either of these things is happening and I can't find any info on the internet, can anyone help?

Comment: Dear Sam, we need more info like MCU type, LEDs connection type, firmware and etc...

Comment: Are you using a cracked version of proteus? I also faced this issue once in my life with a particular version of Proteus. Please share your design file with us.